# AWS Glue Job parallel running got error "Rate exceeded" ThrottlingException Status Code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a simple (just print hello) glue 2.0 job that runs in parallel, triggered from a step function map. Glue job Maximum concurrency is set to 40 and so as Step Funcitons Map's MaxConcurrency.

[image: Step function in Workflow Studio].

It runs fine if I kicked off under 20 parallel glue jobs but exceeding that (I tried max 35 parallel) I got intermittent errors like this:

> Rate exceeded (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
> ThrottlingException; Request ID: 0a350b23-2f75-4951-a643-20429799e8b5;
> Proxy: null)

I've checked the service quotas documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glue.html and my account settings. 200 max should have handled my 35 parallel jobs happily.

[image: AWS Service Quotas screenshot]

There are no other Glue job scheduled to be run at the same time in my aws account.

Should I just blindly request to increase the quota and see it fixed or is there anything I can do to get around this?

Comment: The problem is pro a alt that your map state is trying to run e.g. 40 jobs within a tenth of a second and that hits an API throttling. Do you have a retry behavior configured, that retries in throttling errors?

Comment: @luk2302 that's good point. No I don't have any retry behaviour configured. I'll see if I can get it fixed that way.

Comment: Yep, adding a Retry did solve the issue. However, I don't know what error to catch so I used States.ALL (which is too broad). Do you know what's the error name for this ThrottlingException? I've tried "ThrottlingException" and "Rate Exceeded" but doen't work :-(

Comment: I am not familiar with the specifics, no. I would try to look at the exception that is thrown, how it is displayed within the step function, under what name, maybe look at the glue + step function docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to luk2302 and Robert for the suggestions.
Based on their advice, I reach to a solution.

Add a retry in the Glue Task. (I tried IntervalSeconds 1 and BackoffRate 1 but that's too low and didn't work)

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun",
"Type": "Task",
"Retry": [
  {
    "ErrorEquals": [
      "Glue.AWSGlueException"
    ],
    "BackoffRate": 2,
    "IntervalSeconds": 2,
    "MaxAttempts": 3
  }
]
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The quota that you are hitting is not the concurrent job quota of Glue, but the Start Job Run API quota. You basically requested too many job runs per second. If possible just wait in between every Start Job Run call.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Not sure if I can delay Glue invoking in Step Functions Map but will try implementing a retry behaviours as suggested by @luk2302

Comment: Retry should work in that case.